# Counting up occurrences in a column based on another column

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

I have a dataframe in R in which every observation is a paper. The continent column denotes which continent the paper looks at and the impacts column denotes which "impacts" it mentions (0 for not mentioned).

It looks like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is this:
[image]

I was successful in producing the data in that second picture by doing the following:

```
water <- with(df,tapply(Water,Continent,FUN=sum))
colnames(water) <- "Water"

temp<- with(df,tapply(Temperature,Continent,FUN=sum))
colnames(temp) <- "Temperature")

new.df <- cbind(water,temp)
new.df2 <- cbind(newColName = rownames(new.df), new.df)
rownames(new.df) <- 1:nrow(new.df)


new.df2 <- melt(new.df2)
names(new.df2) <- c("Continent", "Impact", "Occurrences")
```

However, I have 50 columns I would like to do this for and am struggling to find a method that would do it succinctly. In sum what i am trying to do is find a easy way to:

1. sum each "*impact*" column (every column except the *paper number* and *continent* columns) BY the *continent* column
2. melt it so that for each *Continent* and each *impact* it tells me the number of *occurrences* that *impact* appears in that *continent*

Answer (score 1):

I think a `tidyverse` approach would look like this, but hard to know for sure without testing on a portion of your data:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(
  df1, 
  -c(`paper#`, Continent), 
  names_to = "Impact", 
  values_to = "Occurrences"
) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Continent, Impact) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Occurrences = sum(Occurrences))
```